# Windows 10 blue screen error occurs sometimes when booting from shutdown

Tags: windows-10, ssd

I've had this computer for a while and just recently started having  this problem. If I shut down the computer and boot it up again, if I press F11 to get into boot menu and select the top option "Windows boot manager" then the boot proceeds normally and works fine. If I don't, the computer ends in [this](https://postimg.cc/YvxXZWwn) error. In my boot heirachy, the windows boot manager is first so it should attempt to boot from that immediately. I have tried dsim /online /ScanHealth and /RestoreHealth but it didn't help. I have 2 SSDs in my machine. I have also tried re-installing windows and checking the state of the drives. Both say "good" in the Samsung ssd management tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the error message in the picture, you could check hardware. Make sure to remove and unplug all peripheral devices you connected lately. Then  restart your PC a few times and look for changes.

If the issue still persists, reconfigure BIOS settings and restart PC to see if it solved.

Meanwhile, you could refer to this link:

https://www.kapilarya.com/a-required-device-isnt-connected-or-cant-be-accessed-0xc000000e-windows-10

Hope these are helpful.

Comment: I reset the bios to default and now the screen doesn't even start. It turns the fans on and all but then it shuts down again. I fixed that by pressing the clear CMOS button. It now works perfectly. Would you like to edit your answer? It was on the right track, but the CMOS was the issue not the BIOS.

Answer (score 1):

I would try repairing your computer first with a USB with Windows 10 on it. You will first need to download the Microsoft Windows Creation tool at. https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10

You can then follow these steps.

1) Boot from the Windows 10 bootable USB.
2) Click Repair your computer.
3) Click Advanced Options.
4) Click Troubleshoot.
5) Click Startup repair.
6) Follow the onscreen instruction.

Comment: I have tried this solution and it didn't work for me personally.

Comment: @Dextication Try updating your bios to the latest version. Also try updating all your drivers and seeing if that fixes the issue.